# How can I get the current Trace Switch programatically?

Tags: c#, web-config, system.diagnostics

In my `web.config` I have:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
    <add name="logLevelSwitch" value="1" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Is there a way that I could call, for example:

`System.Diagnostics.TraceSwitch["logLevelSwitch"]`to get the current value?

Comment: did u get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've defined the switch value in your `web.config` file, it's easy to get this value from your application by creating a [`TraceSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.traceswitch%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with the same name:

```
private static TraceSwitch logSwitch = new TraceSwitch("logLevelSwitch",
    "This is your logLevelSwitch in the config file");

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // you can get its properties value then:
    Console.WriteLine("Trace switch {0} is configured as {1}",
        logSwitch.DisplayName,
        logSwitch.Level.ToString());

    // and you can use it like this:
    if (logSwitch.TraceError)
        Trace.WriteLine("This is an error");

    // or like this also:
    Trace.WriteLineIf(logSwitch.TraceWarning, "This is a warning");
}
```

Moreover, for this to work, according to the documentation:

> You must enable tracing or debugging to use a switch. The following
>   syntax is compiler specific. If you use compilers other than C# or
>   Visual Basic, refer to the documentation for your compiler.
>
> To enabledebugging in C#, add the `/d:DEBUG` flag to the compiler command line
>   when you compile your code, or you can add `#define DEBUG` to the top of
>   your file. In Visual Basic, add the `/d:DEBUG=True` flag to the compiler
>   command line.
>
> To enable tracing using in C#, add the `/d:TRACE` flag to
>   the compiler command line when you compile your code, or add `#define TRACE` to the top of your file. In Visual Basic, add the `/d:TRACE=True`
>   flag to the compiler command line.